# Save json data from input into database

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl

I get the json data using cURL as an input:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8000/jsontest --data-binary @test.json
```

It is simple json with couple of fields:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "blockId": "9000",
  "spot": {
    "id": "7890",
    "length": 23,
    "name": "test",
    "country": "de"
  },
  "channel": "tv:rtl.de",
  "startTimestamp": "1323872435345",
  "endTimestamp": "13243498394384329"
}
```

And this is my code for getting the data and storing in database:

```
public function test()
    {
        $string = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $json_a = json_decode($string, true);

        foreach ($json_a as $json => $test) {
            $tvib          = new TVIB;
            $tvib->spotid  = $test["spot"]["id"];
            $tvib->name    = $test["spot"]["name"];
            $tvib->channel = $test["channel"];
            $tvib->start   = $test["startTimestamp"];
            $tvib->end     = $test["endTimestamp"];
            $tvib->save();
        }

        var_dump($json_a);
    }
```

When I run cURL request I get this error and a lot of html and js code:

```
ErrorException: Illegal string offset &#039;spot&#039; in file TestController.php on line 18 ($tvib->spotid  = $test["spot"]["id"];)
```

If I run this locally like this:

```
$string = file_get_contents('test.json');
```

everything works fine. But there is obviously problem with php input.

Any suggestions?

PS I use Laravel 5.5

Comment: please print $json_a  variable after json_doceode and give me that output

Comment: It is returning the json from the input. So, I think that is ok.

Comment: PLease print and give me that output because it gives error because error in your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not need foreach. so change code to :

```
public function test()
    {
        $string = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $json_a = json_decode($string, true);

        //foreach ($json_a as $json => $test) {
            $tvib          = new TVIB;
            $tvib->spotid  = $json_a["spot"]["id"];
            $tvib->name    = $json_a["spot"]["name"];
            $tvib->channel = $json_a["channel"];
            $tvib->start   = $json_a["startTimestamp"];
            $tvib->end     = $json_a["endTimestamp"];
            $tvib->save();
        //}

        var_dump($json_a);
    }
```

Comment: I need foreach in case I get JSON with multiple keys. Btw this solution doesn't work because I get an unknown error - $test not found